# yowsup - Send a message to a group

Tags: python, whatsapp, yowsup

I know this question has been asked before, but it's been about 4-5 years since the latest responses and I think those solutions or even the library itself are not working anymore.

How to send a message to a Whatsapp group using yowsup library?

Assume I have properly installed the library from [here](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) in a Raspberry Pi 3b+. I can send a text message to a single phone number using `yowsup-cli demos -c config -s xxxxxxx "message"`, but cant send it to a group using the GJID (failed to fetch keys for xxxx@g.us error).
Can you confirm that this is still possible or do you know a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some days, you cant send messages to groups. An [issue on Github](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/issues/3118) is opened. We have to wait.